# How to Get sum of elements in the array found between two integers using python

Tags: python

Given an array `A = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]`,
write a function that receives two integers as parameters. The function
returns the sum of elements in the array found between those two integers.

For example, if we use 20 and 50 as parameters, the function should return
140.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` and `sum`.

```
g = lambda x,y : sum(A[A.index(x):A.index(y)+1])
g(20,50)
```

---

```
140
```